# Get macro value from a compiled binary (with debug)

Tags: linux, debugging, macros, binary, decompiling

I need to determine the value of a specific macro the binary was compiled with.

The file is a Linux shared library file.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given that macros are handled by a preprocessor, even the actual compiler is not aware of them. The only option is to reverse engineer the cod, find the place where you know the macro is used and extract the value from there.

**Edit:** I've just checked DWARF specification, the standard defines `.debug_macinfo` section especially to store debug info about macros, this section contains a `DW_MACINFO_define` record for each defined macro.

So, if you have a debug version of the library, you can try to use `dwarfdump -m` or `readelf --debug-dump=macro` to extract this info.

However: I've tried it on a few libraries in my system, and none of them contained any macro records. By default `gcc` doesn't emit them, the library has to be compiled with `gcc -g3` (the switch increases the debug info level). This is sort of bad news for you, I suppose.

Comment: So you are telling me that there is no way to dig this from debug information?

Comment: Hmm, actually I incorrectly assumed the library is compiled without the debug info. Indeed, dwarf can be helpful, let me updated the answer in a moment.